# How to insert only non-optional values from Avro file into BigQuery table using Java API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, avro

Here is my Avro schema:

```json
{
  "namespace": "example.gcp",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Client",
  "fields": [{
      "name": "id",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "phone",
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And partly reworked code from GCP BigQuery samples on GitHub, which loads all fields from Avro file (stored in Google Cloud Storage) into table (BigQuery).

```java
public static ModelAndView loadAvroFromGCS(String datasetName, String tableName, String sourceUri) {
  String message;

  try {
    BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
    LoadJobConfiguration loadConfig =
      LoadJobConfiguration.of(tableId, sourceUri, FormatOptions.avro());

    Job job = bigquery.create(JobInfo.of(loadConfig));

    job = job.waitFor();

    message = "Successfully loaded data file to " + tableName;
  } catch (BigQueryException | InterruptedException e) {
    message = "Error: " + e.getMessage();
  }
  return new ModelAndView("index")
    .addObject("datasetName", datasetName)
    .addObject("message", message);
}
```

The question is how to change my code to save non-optional fields `("id", "name")` in `table_1` and all fields `("id", "name", "phone", "address")` into `table_2` in one dataset?

Comment: Whats your issue? You want only the ID and NAME in table1, not the other fields?

Comment: Do you want to do both tasks in the same process?  Because an option you can try is  load all the fields in table1, then query (id, name) and load the result in table2. [Creating a table from a query result](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_a_table_from_a_query_result) this documentation cold be used as reference.